# Bootstrap / Blazor - image click link, nothing occur on click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, blazor

In my Bootstrap 4.5 / Blazor app I try to add a simple HTML link around an image.
Then when I click on it I wish to navigate to another URL.

So, I use the simple <a href"..."><img ...> pattern! But nothing occur when I click on it!

How is it possible ?

I have try NavLink, it is the same behavior... no navigation.

What is strange is that, if I click the link, the URL in the browser change,
but the page does not refresh/reload. If I refresh the page manually, I'm on the
new page. It seems that clicking does not do a StateHasChanged or something
like that. It looks to be a Blazor issue. (btw, I use NavLink now, but it does not help).

Somethine else, I'm already on the "Post" page, I just want to change the ID !

Here some code, but not sure it help:

```
<a href="/post/54c031cc-38f4-84e5-5cfd-39f5ff75c3b0"><img src="https://localhost:44359/cdn/e_76372856-f7a0-49cc-d3d9-39f5ad58ad6d/faef9dc96dacaea7d60639f5ff75c38e.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid otherpost-img"></a>
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?

PS: I can make it work with an @onclick, but I wish a link because it should be visible for the SEO.

Thx

Comment: You do have a component with this with a page directive something like this? @page "/post/{SomeGuidId}"

Comment: SEO !!! is you link on your main html code (index.html, _Host.cshtml) or in a component ?

Comment: Hi @aguafrommars , my link is in a component. BTW, I have try the full URL too, but it does not help.

Comment: Hi , btw I have a page with @page "/post/{ID}", and it works perfectly ;-)

Comment: Ok, but is a crawler enable to transform your component in html ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I agree with you, when I check the page source code, there is nothing about the component. But, how does the crawler (Google) etc... can do SEO on a blazor web site ? Any idea ? (It is not a SEO killer I hope)

Comment: No, I'm not an SEO specialist

Comment: No repro. Start by replacing the image with a simple text maybe. Tell us what happens in the Dev tools, Console and Network tabs.

Comment: Create a [mcve] for this, we are missing most relelvant details now.  Make sure you include the OnInitialized and OnParamSet methods.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the issue,

Because it is the same page, OnInitializeAsync is not called, but OnParametersSetAsync is !

So, I refresh my page with this:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync() {
     OnAfterRenderAsync(true);
     StateHasChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should call OnAfterRenderAsync() from application code. Not sure if it will do any harm.

Comment: But if this is the solution it reveals you are doing something else very wrong. You simply shouldn't need this.